# rc-time-picker does allow to edit input using keyboard if it is in bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, timepicker

I am using `rc-time-picker` for entering time (https://github.com/react-component/time-picker).

This is the code:

```
<TimePicker 
    style={{ width: 100 }}
    showSecond={false}
    value={this.state.startTime}
    className="appointmentTimePicker"
    onChange={this.handleStartTimeChange}
/>
```

Nothing especial. It is working. However, I noticed that the component does not allow to enter the input time using keyboard when the component is in the bootstrap modal (version of bootstrap 3.3.7). Even not in the bootstrap modal, then it works just fine as in the example (http://react-component.github.io/time-picker/examples/pick-time.html)

I don't know css well. I suspect that it there is some conflict between styles.

Has anyone had such problem? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set enforceFocus prop of react-bootstrap modal to false:

```
<Modal enforceFocus={false}>
```

Hope this will help.